# what is code for jboxes in celing joists that I intend to cover with plywood?

Tags: electrical

If I cover the boxes and properly secure the cables per code can they be hidden or do I have to surface mount them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I put an outlet inside of a wall?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/82714/can-i-put-an-outlet-inside-of-a-wall)

Comment: What is on the other side of the ceiling?

Answer (score 6):

They must be "*accessible without removing any part of the building or structure*".  If they're accessible from below (ceiling fixture box, etc.), then they can be covered. If the only way to access them is from the attic, then covering them with flooring violates the code.

If you create an easily removable cover, then you might get it approved. But simply nailing/screwing down plywood, is likely not acceptable.

> ## National Electrical Code 2014
>
> ### Chapter 3 Wiring Methods
>
> #### Article 314 Outlet, Device, Pull, and Junction Boxes; Conduit Bodies; Fittings; and Handhole Enclosures.
>
> **314.29 Boxes, Conduit Bodies, and Handhole Enclosures to Be Accessible.** Boxes, conduit bodies, and handhole enclosures shall be installed so that the wiring contained in them can be rendered accessible without removing any part of the building or structure, or, in underground circuits, without excavating sidewalks, paving, earth, or other substance that is to be used to establish the finished grade.

Comment: I believe the code allows for them to be installed above a drop ceiling. That could be an option instead of plywood.

Comment: " If the only way to access them is from the attic, then covering them with flooring violates the code." Does the attic not count as an accessible area?

Comment: @GManNickG It sounds like the box(es) are in the attic floor, so covering the floor would make them inaccessible.

Comment: @Tester101: Ah, got it. I suppose that would make sense since they're covering it with plywood, not drywall. :)

Comment: thanks for the code info.Room above so I will have to provide access panels fastened to plywood.

Comment: @dwightr If you do access panels, you should label/mark them in some way.  Also making a note and leaving it in the electrical panel, will be useful for the next guy.