# USB Receptacle with internal ports

Tags: receptacle

I am planning to fish a USB cable from a mounted tablet behind the wall to an outlet box. Is there an outlet receptacle that has an internal USB port? Image below is a common USB receptacle with two USB-A ports on the outside in the white areas. I don't want to pull out the cable from behind the wall and insert it into the port on the outside in the white areas; I want to run the cable inside the box and plug it into a USB port on the receptacle in the black areas.

[image: Leviton receptacle]

**Edit**:
Not sure why Stack Exchange closed this as a duplicate question, except that their algorithm must be flaky again as usual. The question "Can I put an outlet inside of a wall?" is not the same problem. That post is asking if you can put a charger inside the wall. What has that got to do with this question where I am specifically asking if there's an outlet receptacle with a USB port either behind, to the sides or under the inside of the receptacle? In the image above, the receptacle has two USB ports on the outside in the white areas. I am asking if there's a receptacle with a USB port in the black areas of the receptacle.

Comment: Those USB ports are just for charging.  They are data ports.  Those receptacles are only to make money, they take 50 cent receptacles, put in 10 cent USB ports and charge 15 bucks, just so you save plugging in a wallwart.

Comment: What are you trying to power with that USB cable?

Comment: @crip659 there's a bit more to it.  Since the socket needs to be UL listed, the USB port electronics must also, which means they can't cut corners like the el cheapo jobs from China that BigClive is always tearing down.  Also these receptacles *start* at spec-grade, note the self-grounding clip and screw-and-clamp.

Comment: I think the OP wants an outlet like the one shown but with the USB socket in the back of the outlet instead of in the front.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/82714/can-i-put-an-outlet-inside-of-a-wall ...  This doesn't answer the question. The OP has an existing outlet he wants to replace with an outlet that has the USB port on the back instead of the front. He's asking if such an outlet exists.

Comment: Consider using a buck converter; you can run a 12VDC cable inside your walls and connect it to a 5VDC buck converter, optionally with a USB port on the 5V side. That way you can use larger cables (18ga) for the 12v, which means you can run further with decent amperage to your tablet for keeping it charged.

Comment: @David Tay  I agree that your question isn't the same as the "duplicate"  mentioned above. The bottom line in all this is that they don't make an outlet like the one you want because that connection would not be allowed in a junction box with main voltage.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TL;DR **Not legally, and there are better options available.**

**Frame Challenge**

USB was designed to connect computers and peripherals - mice, keyboards, storage devices, audio-visual equipment, etc. Over time it has become the universal 5V power supply, replacing numerous different types of power packs for electronic devices. But the intent was *short distance computer to device communications*. When powered from a wall wart or from a receptacle with integral USB, the "computer to device communications" part falls away. Which really *should* just leave convenience charging of devices that are a computer by themselves (cell phones, tablets, some full computers using high power USB C) or charging of battery-powered non-computer devices (e.g., flashlights, emergency battery power packs for other devices) or powering small stand-alone devices (simply in place of some other wall wart - i.e., just to make things easier because "everyone has USB wall warts lying around).

None of these cases normally calls for long-distance behind-the-wall wiring of power. Which leads to a common abuse of USB: *Using USB for power + WiFi for networking.* Why do people do that? Because USB is readily available for power - any standard receptacle (integral or with a wall wart) or a battery power-pack or a computer. And WiFi is readily available for communications. It sounds great on paper: As long as you have regular 120V power nearby and WiFi within range, you can plug in a video camera, security sensor, doorbell, etc. But there are a lot of problems with this:

- If you need to go more than ~ 15 feet, USB cables are harder to find, and chaining the cheapies doesn't work well.
- USB cables are not designed to be run through walls. In particular, you can't run *just the wire* and then put on the ends, the way you can with twisted pair Ethernet.
- Any networking is subject to a deliberate router hack or disconnect. But WiFi is vulnerable to routine direct replacement (new default SSID and password), deliberate factory reset to solve problems (assuming there is a factory-default SSID and password that was changed for security purposes) and other problems. Wired networking is only subject to wiring issues (which also affect power via USB).

The good news is that there is a technology designed *specifically* for this situation: Power over Ethernet.

- Long distance - 100 meters (328 feet)
- Cables (if properly rated) can be safely run inside walls, ceilings, etc.
- Cables can be run between punched-down jacks with factory assembled patch cables between the jacks and devices.
- High speed connections (1 Gig. with nothing special, higher speeds possible).
- Power source can be located in a secure location (e.g., PoE switch next to the router in a secure closet).
- Multiple devices can be powered from a single 120V connection (e.g., 8 or 16 devices on a single PoE switch).

---

*Original answer:*

There are two kinds of wire/connections/etc. in most US buildings:

- 120V/240V AC. This includes every standard 15A or 20A receptacle, whether it includes USB or not, most light fixtures, light switches, bigger receptacles (e.g., 30A for dryer, 40A for oven, etc.), junction boxes (connecting the wires between all those devices), main panel, subpanel, etc. Everything inside these boxes/devices/panels must be able to coexist in 120V/240V land. Which means proper insulation, design and certification (e.g., UL or ETL listing).
- Low voltage. This includes telephones (POTS), ethernet and other network cables, coaxial cable (for TV or networking), alarm cable, HVAC thermostat wiring, doorbell wiring, speaker cables, HDMI and other video cables between TVs, computers and other devices, etc.

And never the twain shall meet.

Any transition has to be done in an approved way. That can be a receptacle that includes low voltage USB connections on the outside. That can be a doorbell/thermostat transformer that is mounted to a metal junction box so that it gets 120V power from inside a box and provides low voltage outside the box. But it can't, by definition, include a USB cable *inside* a junction box (i.e., inside the 120V/240V domain) because standard USB cables - and the devices they connect to - are not designed for that use.

The quick & easy fix is to do what alarm companies have done for a long time. Plug in a wall wart (or in the case of USB, yes you can use a receptacle with a built-in USB connector) and then run a cable from the wall wart or USB connector around outside the box (even "poke through the wall just outside the box) and fish it up or down to where you need it.

But really USB is the wrong tool for that. USB cables are simply not designed for long distances and permanent installations. If the goal is to power a remote device such as a video camera that requires data as well as power, then take a look at power over ethernet. Power over ethernet is designed for much longer distances than USB and combines data and power - with your USB-to-receptacle idea you are only getting power and, I suspect, trying to get data over WiFi which raises a lot of concerns. Note that power over ethernet is still low voltage, but the infrastructure is available to handle long runs and permanent installations properly, unlike USB. If your goal is to simply power some device that does *not* have any communications needs, then you may be better off with something other than USB - e.g., a traditional wall wart (like for an alarm system) that can be extended with one-pair cable over long distances rather than using USB cables.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt you'll find one with a UL listing. You can't have low voltage connections like that in the same box as the main voltage.